# What are campaign packages?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a requirement where I have build 4 campaign packages in marketing cloud . Can anyone help by understanding what are campaign packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think its just the packaging of various components within a Campaign in Marketing Cloud. For e.g. a campaign may contain Emails, Lists, Data Extensions, Journeys etc. This collectively can be called as a Campaign package.

There is no precise term as 'Campaign Package' in Marketing CLoud